# Is every abstract vector a tensor?

Tags: linear-algebra, tensors, multilinear-algebra, dual-spaces

I have heard that not all vectors are tensors (for example, if your vector is an element of a vector space of nxm matrices where n≠m, then I was told that it is not a tensor). Though I don't see an issue with the following logic:

If we take any vector, you could consider it to be a map that brings elements of the dual space of its vector space to a field. So by the definition that a tensor is a multilinear map with a codomain that is a field, a vector would be a tensor because it maps from its dual space to a field.

I am wondering if someone could point out where I am going wrong here.

Comment: First "tensors" are not "matrices" although the can be written, in given coordinate system, as matrices.  But the certainly don't have to be written as square matrices.  In fact, in n dimensions, vectors are either $\begin{pmatrix}n \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$ or $\begin{pmatrix}1 \\ n \end{pmatrix}$ tensors.  The category  "tensors" includes "vectors".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can regard a vector $v \in V$ as a linear map from $V^*$ to the underlying field of $V$, and as such it is a $(1,0)$ tensor. Similarly, a dual vector $u\in V^*$ is a $(0,1)$ tensor.

I am not sure what you mean by “if your vector is a non-square matrix”. I cannot think of a natural (i.e. basis independent) way of representing a vector as a non-square matrix.